# access 2nd level of json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a data object that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "key": "K1204", 
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "Both", 
        "values": [
          {
            "key": 1420070400000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1422748800000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1425168000000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1427846400000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1430438400000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1433116800000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1435708800000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1438387200000, 
            "values": 27927.734942179697
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1441065600000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1443657600000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1446336000000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1448928000000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1451606400000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1454284800000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1456790400000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1459468800000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1462060800000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1464739200000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1467331200000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1470009600000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1472688000000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1475280000000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1477958400000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1480550400000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1483228800000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1485907200000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1488326400000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and what I'm trying to do is get it to look like this:

```
[
      {
        "key": "Both", 
        "values": [
          {
            "key": 1420070400000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1422748800000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1425168000000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1427846400000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1430438400000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1433116800000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1435708800000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1438387200000, 
            "values": 27927.734942179697
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1441065600000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1443657600000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1446336000000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1448928000000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1451606400000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1454284800000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1456790400000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1459468800000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1462060800000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1464739200000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1467331200000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1470009600000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1472688000000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1475280000000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1477958400000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1480550400000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1483228800000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1485907200000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1488326400000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I've tried this:

```
var data_costByScn2 = data3.values

console.log("data3val: ", data_costByScn2)
```

but it returns undefined...how do I get it to return the just the next level in the json object?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "json object".](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) (You may have retrieved the data in JSON format, but by the time you come to access/manipulate it with `data3.values` it isn't JSON, it is an object (or array) that you got by parsing the JSON.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `values` of the first array element.

```
var data_costByScn2 = data3[0].values

console.log("data3val: ", data_costByScn2)
```

```js
var data3 = [
  {
    "key": "K1204", 
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "Both", 
        "values": [
          {
            "key": 1420070400000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1422748800000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1425168000000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1427846400000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1430438400000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1433116800000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1435708800000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1438387200000, 
            "values": 27927.734942179697
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1441065600000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1443657600000, 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1446336000000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1448928000000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1451606400000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1454284800000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1456790400000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1459468800000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1462060800000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1464739200000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1467331200000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1470009600000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1472688000000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1475280000000, 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1477958400000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1480550400000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1483228800000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1485907200000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1488326400000, 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

var data_costByScn2 = data3[0].values

console.log("data3val: ", data_costByScn2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the first object is actually an Array [...] containing 1 item, data3[0].values would actually give you the values you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select first element that is `0` index element:

Try  `Object[0].values`

Example Snippet:

```js
var obj = [{
  "key": "K1204",
  "values": [{
    "key": "Both",
    "values": [{
      "key": 1420070400000,
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": 1422748800000,
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": 1425168000000,
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": 1427846400000,
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": 1430438400000,
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": 1433116800000,
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": 1435708800000,
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": 1438387200000,
      "values": 27927.734942179697
    }, {
      "key": 1441065600000,
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": 1443657600000,
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": 1446336000000,
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": 1448928000000,
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": 1451606400000,
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": 1454284800000,
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": 1456790400000,
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": 1459468800000,
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": 1462060800000,
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": 1464739200000,
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": 1467331200000,
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": 1470009600000,
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": 1472688000000,
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": 1475280000000,
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": 1477958400000,
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": 1480550400000,
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": 1483228800000,
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": 1485907200000,
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": 1488326400000,
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }]
  }]
}]

console.log(obj[0].values)
```