# getting the array length the same across all objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a data object that looks like this:

```
 [
  {
    "key": "k1204", 
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "Both", 
        "values": [
          {
            "key": "1420070400000", 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1422748800000", 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1425168000000", 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1427846400000", 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1430438400000", 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1433116800000", 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1435708800000", 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1438387200000", 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1441065600000", 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1443657600000", 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1446336000000", 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1448928000000", 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1451606400000", 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1454284800000", 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1456790400000", 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1459468800000", 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1462060800000", 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1464739200000", 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1467331200000", 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1470009600000", 
            "values": 36929.200142179696
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1472688000000", 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1488326400000", 
            "values": 36929.2001421797
          }
        ]
      }, 
      {
        "key": "Cloud", 
        "values": [
          {
            "key": "1420070400000", 
            "values": 289819.9054
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1422748800000", 
            "values": 289819.9054
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1425168000000", 
            "values": 289819.9054
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1427846400000", 
            "values": 289819.9054
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1430438400000", 
            "values": 289819.9054
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1433116800000", 
            "values": 289819.9054
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1435708800000", 
            "values": 289819.9054
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1438387200000", 
            "values": 289819.9054
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1441065600000", 
            "values": 289819.9054
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1443657600000", 
            "values": 289819.9054
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1446336000000", 
            "values": 289819.9054
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1448928000000", 
            "values": 289819.9054
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1451606400000", 
            "values": 289819.9054
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1454284800000", 
            "values": 289819.9054
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1456790400000", 
            "values": 289819.9054
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1459468800000", 
            "values": 289819.9054
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1462060800000", 
            "values": 289819.9054
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1464739200000", 
            "values": 289819.9054
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1467331200000", 
            "values": 366563.39859999996
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1470009600000", 
            "values": 366563.39859999996
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1472688000000", 
            "values": 366563.39859999996
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1475280000000", 
            "values": 366563.39859999996
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1477958400000", 
            "values": 366563.39859999996
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1480550400000", 
            "values": 366563.39859999996
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1483228800000", 
            "values": 366563.39859999996
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1485907200000", 
            "values": 366563.39859999996
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1488326400000", 
            "values": 366563.39859999996
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1491004800000", 
            "values": 375564.86380000005
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1493596800000", 
            "values": 375564.8638
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1496275200000", 
            "values": 375564.86380000005
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1498867200000", 
            "values": 375564.8638
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1501545600000", 
            "values": 375564.86380000005
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1504224000000", 
            "values": 375564.86380000005
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1506816000000", 
            "values": 375564.86380000005
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1509494400000", 
            "values": 375564.8638
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1512086400000", 
            "values": 375564.8638
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1514764800000", 
            "values": 499244.1814
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1517443200000", 
            "values": 499244.1814
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1519862400000", 
            "values": 499244.1814
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1522540800000", 
            "values": 499244.1814
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1525132800000", 
            "values": 499244.1814
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1527811200000", 
            "values": 499244.1814
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1530403200000", 
            "values": 499244.18139999994
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1533081600000", 
            "values": 499244.1814
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1535760000000", 
            "values": 499244.18139999994
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1538352000000", 
            "values": 499244.1814
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1541030400000", 
            "values": 499244.1814
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1543622400000", 
            "values": 499244.1814
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1546300800000", 
            "values": 499244.1814
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1548979200000", 
            "values": 499244.18139999994
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1551398400000", 
            "values": 499244.18139999994
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1554076800000", 
            "values": 499244.1814
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1556668800000", 
            "values": 499244.1814
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1559347200000", 
            "values": 499244.1814
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1561939200000", 
            "values": 499244.1814
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1564617600000", 
            "values": 499244.1814
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1567296000000", 
            "values": 499244.18139999994
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1569888000000", 
            "values": 499244.1814
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1572566400000", 
            "values": 499244.1814
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1575158400000", 
            "values": 499244.18139999994
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }, 
  {
    "key": "tre", 
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "On-Prem", 
        "values": [
          {
            "key": "1420070400000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1422748800000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1425168000000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1427846400000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1430438400000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1433116800000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1435708800000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1438387200000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1441065600000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1443657600000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1446336000000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1448928000000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1451606400000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1454284800000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1456790400000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1459468800000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1462060800000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1464739200000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1467331200000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1470009600000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1472688000000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1475280000000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1477958400000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1480550400000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1483228800000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1485907200000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1488326400000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1491004800000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1493596800000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1496275200000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1498867200000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1501545600000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1504224000000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1506816000000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1509494400000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1512086400000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1514764800000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1517443200000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1519862400000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }
        ]
      }, 
      {
        "key": "", 
        "values": [
          {
            "key": "1420070400000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1422748800000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1425168000000", 
            "values": 0
          },
          {
            "key": "1441065600000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1443657600000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1446336000000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1448928000000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1451606400000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1454284800000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1456790400000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1459468800000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1462060800000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1464739200000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1467331200000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1470009600000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1472688000000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1475280000000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1477958400000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1480550400000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1483228800000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1485907200000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1488326400000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1491004800000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1493596800000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1496275200000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1498867200000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1501545600000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1504224000000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1506816000000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1509494400000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1512086400000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1514764800000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1517443200000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1519862400000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1522540800000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1525132800000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1527811200000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1530403200000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1533081600000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1535760000000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1538352000000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1541030400000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1543622400000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1546300800000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1548979200000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1551398400000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1554076800000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1556668800000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1559347200000", 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1561939200000", 
            "values": 0
          }
        ]
      }, 
      {
        "key": "Cloud", 
        "values": [
          {
            "key": "1420070400000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1422748800000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1425168000000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1427846400000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1430438400000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1433116800000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1435708800000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1438387200000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1441065600000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1443657600000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1446336000000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1448928000000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1451606400000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1454284800000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1456790400000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1459468800000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1462060800000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1464739200000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1467331200000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1470009600000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1472688000000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1475280000000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1477958400000", 
            "values": 104732.0298
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1480550400000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1483228800000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1485907200000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1488326400000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1491004800000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1493596800000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1496275200000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1498867200000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1501545600000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1504224000000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1506816000000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1509494400000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1512086400000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1514764800000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1517443200000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1519862400000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1522540800000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1525132800000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1527811200000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1530403200000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1533081600000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1535760000000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1538352000000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1541030400000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1543622400000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1546300800000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1548979200000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1551398400000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1554076800000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1556668800000", 
            "values": 181475.523
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to ensure that the length of the `key, values` arrays are the same so I can plot them on a `stackedAreaChart` using nvd3 since there are two conditions that I need to follow...

1. Series should have the same time scale (range).
2. Series length, i.e. 'values' array length should be the same across all objects in data.

I tried following this fidde: http://jsfiddle.net/krispo1/nR6qN/2/

by doing this in the controller:

```
get_scn_cst_data().then(function(costByScn){

                var data2 = []

                for(i = 0; i < costByScn.length; i++) {
                    console.log("i:", JSON.stringify(costByScn[i].values))
                    var data = costByScn[i].values;

                    if(data && Array.isArray(data)) { 
                            console.log("is array")
                            }

                    data = data.map(function(series){
                              series.values = series.values.map(function(d,i){
                                  return [data[2].values[i][0], d[1]]
                              })
                              return series;
                          });

                }

                console.log("data2: ", JSON.stringify(costByScn));

                $scope.data_costByScn =   costByScn;

})
```

but got this error: `TypeError: data.map is not a function`

----EDIT-----

made changes to fix the array but now getting this error at `Cannot read property 'values' of undefined` at this part:

```
                data = data.map(function(series){
                          series.values = series.values.map(function(d,i){
                              return [data[2].values[i][0], d[1]]
                          })
                          return series;
                      });
```

why does values come back undefined? when I console log data, it looks to be an array with `values`

Comment: `data` refers to `costByScn[i].values[j]`, which is an object, not an array.

Comment: just made an edit...i think I had one to many loops and changed `costByScn[i].values[j]` to `costByScn[i]`

Comment: OK, well `costByScn[i]` isn't an array either, so it doesn't have a `.map()` method. Maybe you want `data = costByScn[i].values`?

Comment: @user2061886: You asked [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051781/access-2nd-level-of-json-object/) only an hour or so ago, in which you were struggling with similar concepts. I understand that learning JS can be difficult, but maybe you could try playing around with `console.log` to see what the value *just before* the error was before opening another thread.

Comment: yeah, I had marked an answer there and didn't know if I should add to it or ask another question since they were of different nature but same data set. I tried using console log to get the output of the object but sitll can't seem to get far...

Answer (score 2):

simply the **type error** means you are trying to invoking .map on something which is not an array!

before sending that **data** to the .map verify it to be a valid array

you can use :`if(data && Array.isArray(data)) { 
// your login goes here...
}`